# How to add SQL Query to Excel database using Crystal Reports in C#

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am creating a small windows application, with crystal reports, my data is stored in Excel file, currently I have no problem in creating crystal report and getting output correctly but my requirement is to filter data using Where clause. Is it possible to add SQL query to such excel data...if not then what should I do..any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Range.Autofilter method. It's like SQL selection where you can use 'LIKE' or '=' operator.

Comment: Or add your Excel file in Access where you can apply your SQL queries.

Comment: my problem is how to get connected between VS & the excel & how to start using SQL query to such excel data

Comment: Excel data is not Database. You can't apply SQL queries to it. Connecting VS with excel can be realized by `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` If you still want to use SQL queries you can read [link]http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-sql-statements-ms-excel-41193.html[/link]

Comment: thnx 4 ur comment, but when i click on the url

Sorry, the page you're looking for can't be found.

Comment: [link](smallbusiness.chron.com/use-sql-statements-ms-excel-41193.html) try this